# How to use a textbox to open a new page in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a private page on my website that you need a code to get into,  but my script isn't working. I'm trying to make it so that once you type the code it goes into the new page and if you type it wrong it says "incorrect". I tried this script but something isn't working.

```js
  var Username = document.forms['Form']['Username'].value;
   
  function openPage(){
   if((Username === "Design Castle Private")||(Password === "test"))
    {
    window.location.href = "http://design-castle.co.nf/PrivateSubmitted.html";
   }
   else{
    alert('Information Incorrect!')
   }
  }
```

```html
  <form method="post" name="Form" onsubmit="return openPage()">
   <h4>Company Code:</h4><input type="text" id="Username">
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: you are reading the username once - move it into the function.

Comment: also this isn't very secure

Comment: What would you recommend ?

Comment: For one, your code snippet doesn't seem to have a password field. Two, don't do this, as this isn't secure *at all*. JavaScript logic is open to anyone who accesses the site.  A simple way to make a basic Username/Password login would be to make a POST request to a .php file. A fast Google yields this: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-login-form.html. If you REALLY want to do this in JavaScript, learn NodeJS, but that's a whole different story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps (in plain js this time around). It should give you the desired behavior, but as other posts have mentioned, it is very unsafe. I have also dropped the method from the form and put an id into your input element. As soon as you have a password input element, you can also put that into your conditional as you have before, but again it's not ideal. Try it out! :)

```
<form name="Form" onsubmit="openPage(event)">
    <h4>Company Code:</h4>
    <input type="text" id="username" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

function openPage(event){
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;

    if(username === "Design Castle Private"){
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = "http://design-castle.co.nf/PrivateSubmitted.html";
        } else{
            alert('Information Incorrect!');
        }
    }
```